# Regex to Increment a Number by 1 in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

How would I use a regex in Visual Studio 2005's search / replace to increment a set of numbers by 1?

The search term is either `{:z}` or `{[0-9]+}`. I am unsure of the replace term. Using "`\1`" simply substitutes the tagged string, but doesn't allow for addition to it. For instance "`\1 + 1`" places "`42 + 1`" into the text if 42 was the tagged number.

Using "`=`" or "`\=`" as in the following question doesn't work (again, the `=` is simply placed in the resulting text).

This is the way to  do this in VIM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420797/vim-regex-increment-all-numbers-by-1

Comment: Hmm... regex only finds text within text, it does not have any arithmatic operations built into it, so it can not for example take "9" and carry it into 2 digits to form "10".

Comment: This is possible in vim because you can evaluate arbitrary vim functions in the replacement. Unless VS has such a feature it's probably impossible. Why do this, by the way? Couldn't you factor any magic numbers into variables or defines?

Comment: You can create a simple program taking Text and Regex as input and generating the required text.
But I think there is not inbuilt replace with increment functionality.

Comment: I would advice you to use Notepad++ macros instead.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers, everybody. @sapht The numbers I was incrementing are already a set of #defines. I added a couple of items and renumbered some of them to keep them in logical order for what they represent.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the exact answer to your question for which I hope you'll excuse me but I do hope it could be useful ;-)

There is a tool I created named [ProjectBuildCounter](http://build.codeplex.com/). It is free, easy to use, no setup hassles and visual studio versions mess. Could use it for as many projects you want. You can [download here](http://build.codeplex.com/). Usage info is [available here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuD7jpQmYck).

Comment: Please do not use Super User to advertise your software - at least add the disclaimer that you are the author.